# Decision based on decision tree

Tags: decision-theory, decision-trees, decision-problems

Based on a text I created a decision tree. This decision tree shows options A, B and C. I calculated the value that could be expected for each decision and the highest one would be that of option C with 5625$.

Now I want to know, if every person would choose C without knowing the risk attitudes of the person? Would a person that is risk averse also choose C for example?
[image]

Comment: is the diagram missing some weights for each decision?

Comment: No, only the possibility of illness is mentioned in the text. There is no weight for rain or sunshine mentioned.

Comment: can you share the text please?